# KeyError when running CoherenceModel

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, keyerror, topic-modeling

I have a variable, `data_words`, which is my corpus and is a list of lists of strings (tokens).

Also, I have a variable `topics`, a list of list of strings (tokens).

Now, I want to find the 'c_v' score for my topics. To do so, I run the following code:

```
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel

id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_words)
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in data_words]
coherence_score = CoherenceModel(topics=topics,
                          texts = data_words, 
                          corpus= corpus, 
                          dictionary= id2word, 
                          coherence= 'c_v', 
                          topn=20).get_coherence()
```

However, when I run this, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 448, in _ensure_elements_are_ids
    return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 448, in <listcomp>
    return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])

KeyError: 'afgelopen'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-570-8aef06174d6c>", line 1, in <module>
    coherence_score = CoherenceModel(topics=topics,

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.topics = topics

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 430, in topics
    topic_token_ids = self._ensure_elements_are_ids(topic)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 451, in _ensure_elements_are_ids
    return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 451, in <listcomp>
    return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\coherencemodel.py", line 450, in <genexpr>
    topic = (self.dictionary.id2token[_id] for _id in topic)

KeyError: 'lamp'
```

The error indicates that I am passing a `str` where I should have passed an id.
However, the variables and variables types align with the formats described in [the documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/coherencemodel.html).

What can I do to get the coherence scores?

Comment: can you please update your question indicating how you define `data_words` and `topics` ?

Comment: I've defined it as follows:

`data_words`, = a list of lists of strings (tokens).
`topics` =  a list of list of strings (tokens).

What other information do you need?